# UITabBarController does not appear in view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UIView that is pushing a UITableViewController that is contained inside of a UITabBarController.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ARViewController : UITableViewController<UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    IBOutlet    UITabBarController*     tabBarController;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITabBarController* tabBarController;

@end
```

Here is my implementation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.title = @"AR";

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    tabBarController.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```

My UITabBarController is referenced to Files Owner. Why is it not appearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITabBarController is always used as 'root controller'. Maybe you can try to use a root controller to contain a tableview. And it's not a common method to add a tabbar as a subview to a tableview.

Comment: Can you explain "root controller" to me? How can I use a root controller to contain a tableview?

Comment: RootController is something like views container used to organize other views. Mostly iphone app use NavigationController and TabBarController to organize other views, that's very convenient. For using a tabbar controller, you can easily drag a 'UITabBarController' into your Mainwindow.xib via Interface Builder, check that controller, you can find many interesting settings and easy to find where to 'insert' your UITableViewController into that  UITabBarControlle.
I suggest you the book 'Begin iPhone development' written by Dave Mark and Jeff LaMarche. A great book.